# Return a specified data at row "index" from an SQLite query

Tags: android, google-maps

I have this query:

```
Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, columns_descri,null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

And i want it to return the data of `column_descri` at row "index". "Index" is a paramater in my function:

```
 public void showOverlay (OverlayItem overlay, int index)
        {
        db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String[] columns_descri = new String[] {COL_DESCRI};

        Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, columns_descri,null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToPosition(index)) {
         //show an AlertDialog with description of row index
```

How can i acheive that ?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String res = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(COL_DESCRI));
cur.close();
```

Comment: I did that after `if (cur.moveToPosition(index)) {` => `String description = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DESCRI));` But my problem is that the AlertDialog does not shows just one time, but many times(6) when i tap on only one marker.

Comment: Than you should check how many times `showOverlay` called. May be it called 6 times.

Comment: I don't think that the the function is called many times, it is: `public boolean onTap(int index)
     
        {
 
              showOverlay(getItem(index),index) ;
 
             
 
              return super.onTap(index) ;
 
        }` In function of marker index it'll show its description by browsing the column "COL_DESCRI" in row of index.